# App just forcecloses and stops working, why?

Tags: java, android, listview, file-io, android-listview

I'm a newbie android developer and I am making, or trying to make a File explorer that wil be capable of opening almost all file types. From music files, through video files, document files and many others. BUT, I came across a huge problem that my app compiled successfully but it does not open. Here is my code:

```
package com.tstudios.openit;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root;
    private TextView myPath;
    private ImageView mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        getDir(root);
    }

    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if(!dirPath.equals(root))
        {
            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent()); 
        }
        String filename = f.getName();
        String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
        String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
        TextView row=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rowtext);
        //if(extension=="jpg"){
    //mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dirPath));
        //}
        //if(extension!=null){
                //row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_launcher,0,0,0);
        //}

        Arrays.sort(files, filecomparator);

        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            File file = files[i];    

            if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                }else{
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            } 
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList); 
    }

 Comparator<? super File> filecomparator = new Comparator<File>(){

        public int compare(File file1, File file2) {

            if(file1.isDirectory()){
                if (file2.isDirectory()){
                    return     String.valueOf(file1.getName().toLowerCase()).compareTo(file2.getName().toLowerCase());
                }else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }else {
                if (file2.isDirectory()){
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return     String.valueOf(file1.getName().toLowerCase()).compareTo(file2.getName().toLowerCase());
                }
            }

        }  
    };


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(path.get(position));
        String filename = file.getName();
        String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
        String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(extension=="jpg"){

                mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename));
                getDir(path.get(position));
            }else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show(); 
                } 
        }else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

        }

    }

}
```

and this is logcat I get when I lauch the app, btw I am using Sony Xperia Z1 Compact if that helps

```
08-28 12:10:54.779    4169-4169/com.tstudios.openit D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-28 12:10:54.779    4169-4169/com.tstudios.openit W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread     exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4164cd88)
08-28 12:10:54.789    4169-4169/com.tstudios.openit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tstudios.openit, PID: 4169
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity                 ComponentInfo{com.tstudios.openit/com.tstudios.openit.MainActivity}:         java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
            at com.tstudios.openit.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And another question, how to put icons before file names ? Depending on extension
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: `mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);` put this line inside `onCreate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the

```
mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
```

to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`, leaving just the member variable declaration at the class level:

```
private ImageView mImageView;
```

Before `onCreate()` there's no window yet for the activity and you'll get the NPE.

Before `setContentView()` there's no view hierarchy to search from and a null is returned.

Comment: i moved it there but now it can't find the variable m.ImageView because it's declared under onCreate. can you please send full code ?

Comment: Oh, I moved it under onListItemClick amd it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
private ImageView mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
```

to use `findViewById` you need a valid `Activity`. It happens after the activity has been attached

Comment: and after calling `setContentView()`

Comment: well that's not necessary. It will, of course, return a `null` object. Thanks @WarrenFaith

Answer (score 0):

Place this  line **private ImageView mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);** after **setContentView** . It will resolve null pointer exception. After this, if you get any other exception, Pls tell.